# kNN - How to locate the nearest neighbors in the training matrix based on the calculated distances

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, knn

I am trying to implement k-nearest neighbor algorithm using python. I ended up with the following code. However, I am struggling with finding the index of the items that are the nearest neighbors. The following function will return the distance matrix. However I need to get the indices of these neighbors in the `features_train` (the input matrix to the algorithm).

```
def find_kNN(k, feature_matrix, query_house):
    alldistances = np.sort(compute_distances(feature_matrix, query_house))
    dist2kNN = alldistances[0:k+1]
    for i in range(k,len(feature_matrix)):
        dist = alldistances[i]
        j = 0
        #if there is closer neighbor
        if dist < dist2kNN[k]:
        #insert this new neighbor 
            for d in range(0, k):
                if dist > dist2kNN[d]:
                    j = d + 1
            dist2kNN = np.insert(dist2kNN, j, dist)
            dist2kNN = dist2kNN[0: len(dist2kNN) - 1]
    return dist2kNN    

print find_kNN(4, features_train, features_test[2])
```

Output is:

```
[ 0.0028605   0.00322584  0.00350216  0.00359315  0.00391858]
```

Can someone help me to identify these nearest items in the  `features_train`?

Comment: what is your `query_house` doing exactly ?

Comment: @MMF it is just a single instance of house in the test set. `features_train` contains all other house items

Comment: Why don't you use `sklearn` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will suggest to use the python library `sklearn` that has a `KNeighborsClassifier` from which, once fitted, you can retrieve the nearest neighbors you are looking for :

Try this out:

```
# Import
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

# Instanciate your classifier
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=4) #k=4 or whatever you want
# Fit your classifier
neigh.fit(X, y) # Where X is your training set and y is the training_output
# Get the neighbors
neigh.kneighbors(X_test, return_distance=False) # Where X_test is the sample or array of samples from which you want to get the k-nearest neighbors
```

Comment: sir, thanks for your answer! However, I am supposed to do this using python.